# Restarting Application using broadcast - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-ndk

I am working with Android open source code. I am modifying the Launcher application such that the Launcher and homescreen Icons can be changed through an application.

Now, I have an issue here. In order for the Launcher icons to refresh after pressing the 'Apply new icons' button from the app, I need to restart the Launcher - onDestroy, then onCreate.

Observing the open source workflow after inserting logs, I observed that, the following callback sequence is executed in the case of restarting the launcher during Locale change.

I understand, Locale change is in some way related to ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED and whenever it happens, Launcher is restarted using the sequence given in log.

In order to substantiate my point that Launcher is restarted on Locale changed, I did the following test. I did 'Apply new icons' and checked home screen, icons are not changed, then I changed the Language and came back to home screen, and icons were changed! Also, the log indicates clearly, Launcher is restarted during Locale change.

```
01-01 00:02:19.960: INFO/ActivityManager(264): app/com.android.launcher[RESUMED]  app.idle/true ...resumeTopActivityLocked
01-01 00:02:19.968: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside  onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()****
01-01 00:02:19.968: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside onDestroy()****
01-01 00:02:19.968: DEBUG/LauncherApplication(564): setLauncher
01-01 00:02:19.968: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside unbindWorkspaceAndHotseatItems()****
01-01 00:02:19.992: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside onWindowVisibilityChanged()****
01-01 00:02:19.992: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside updateRunning()**** autoAdvanceRunning = false
01-01 00:02:19.992: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside onDetachedFromWindow()****
01-01 00:02:19.992: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside updateRunning()**** autoAdvanceRunning = false
01-01 00:02:19.992: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside AppWidgetResetObserver()****
01-01 00:02:19.992: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside onCreate()****
```

The question I have here is, after pressing the 'Apply new icons' from the external application, can I explicitly invoke the Broadcast **Action ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED** ? If yes, the Launcher will be restarted using the log sequence I gave, and I have my new icons in the home screen and my issue is resolved.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> can I explicitly invoke the Broadcast Action ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED ?

No. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED), "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system."

> If yes, the Launcher will be restarted using the log sequence I gave

Not necessarily. You assume that the broadcast is the trigger for "the log sequence I gave". [Correlation does not imply causation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).

Since you are modifying the launcher, you are welcome to have it respond to some other custom broadcast `Intent` of yours, which your other app sends. You are then welcome to respond to that broadcast by manually reloading all things that might have changed.

Comment: Thanks commonsware, I understand. One thing in common between the custom intent that I broadcast, and the ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED on changing language is, both invoke the Launcher. For 'Apply new icons' launcher restart case, after observing the workflow using logs for language change, I precisely followed every single step for launcher restart on language change and applied the same for icons change case.

Comment: but unfortunately, following is the log sequence I get which indicates that , it always go to onResume() `01-01 00:03:37.796: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside updateRunning()**** autoAdvanceRunning = false
01-01 00:03:37.804: INFO/ActivityManager(264): app/com.android.launcher[RESUMED] app.idle/true ...resumeTopActivityLocked
01-01 00:03:37.804: DEBUG/Launcher(564): ****Inside onResume()****`. whereas in language change case, it follows the sequence onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), onDestroy(), onCreate()